# Including NPM module in React file: Webpack can't resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Based on what I have put together reading [here](http://frontendinsights.com/how-create-react-component-publish-npm/) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder), the way to publish a react module to NPM, and then use it in another project while the component itself is in the `node_modules` director should look like this

1. write a module, then export it
2. fill in the `main` property of `package.json` with the name of the script, in my case, `dist/index.js`
3. `npm install` it from the project where you want to include it
4. serve the script statically from server.

   - I have something that looks like this to serve the js file: 
     `app.use('public/componentA', express.static(path.join('node_modules', 'componentA'));`
   - this is not the totally real code, but it works, I can see the JS in the browser if I load it.
5. require component

*index.js*

```
var React = require('react');
var Component = require('../public/componentA/');
var hook = document.getElementById('hook');
React.render(Component, hook);
```

However when I try to webpack this I get the error

> ERROR in ./lib/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory './public/componentA' in /Users/me/Documents/tests/reactcomponenttest/lib

What here is preventing me from using my module? I am supposing that the `public` dir is not available anywhere but the specific port. If that's the case how do we use the node `use` suggestion from my second link?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/981

Answer (score 1):

You have to require the module by it’s name. If you published the module with the name `componentA`, write something like this: 
`var Component = require('componentA');`

Step 4. is not necessary at all. Webpack bundles all your JavaScript files into one file. So if you `require(‘componentA')` it will basically copy the content of componentA’s `dist/index.js` into the final `bundle.js`.

At the end you simply serve the `bundle.js` .