# How to include stylesheets and javascripts from npm install

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, npm-install

This feels so basic that no one bothers to explain it. I'm trying to use the `fullcalendar` library in my app. In their documentation under «Basic Usage», I found this:

> The first step in embedding a calendar on a web page is to have the
>   right JavaScript and CSS files. Make sure you are including the
>   FullCalendar stylesheet, as well as the FullCalendar, jQuery, and
>   Moment JavaScript files, in the  of your page:
>
> ```
> <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
> <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
> <script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
> <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
> ```

And under «Download», it says this:

> You can install FullCalendar via NPM:
>
> `$ npm install fullcalendar`

What I don't understand is, where do I find the `fullcalendar.css`, `jquery.min.js`, `moment.min.js` and `fullcalendar.js` files to include?

NPM install doesn't download a directory into my downloads directories that I can drag into my project, it adds files to my `node_modules` directory, and I doubt I'm supposed to go rummaging in there for the files (my `node_modules` directory has thousands of directories in it). I tried using Webpack to bundle the js files, thinking it might automatically include them in the bundle, but that didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? If the answer is obvious, why not just post an answer?

Comment: "..I'm supposed to go rummaging in there for the files" well, this is actually what you have to do.

Comment: Oh really? That's surprising to me, but not difficult.

Comment: Wait, so I'm actually supposed to drag these files out of the node_modules and into my project with the structure project/lib and project/fullcalendar...or am I supposed to just give these src props ultra long paths?

Comment: npm does the job of managing versions and downloading the packages for you :) for development purpose, it's fine to refer to "node_modules/somelib/somelib.js" but for production, you may want to use Grunt or Gulp to build your resources

Comment: Thanks. Why was this considered a bad question? I've been trying to figure this out for hours, and I never came across anything about Grunt or Gulp.

Comment: you're welcome mate. here is a dummy project I created to play a little bit with Grunt... I recommend you to try some tutorial with Grunt of Gulp https://github.com/jeandersonbc/grunt-labs

Comment: Well... the question was about linking resources downloaded from NPM. as simply as it is, you just had to literally add the relative path to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include scripts located inside the node\_modules folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder)

Comment: Thanks @KurtVandenBranden, 2 years later ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to have any of the script tags or stylesheet links in the header if you use Webpack, with this `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "./calendar.js",
  output: { filename: "bundle.js" },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/.js?$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And you need to `npm install babel`. And if you want Webpack to handle your CSS files for you too, you can `npm install` `style-loader` and `css-loader`. Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "full_calendar_demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Then my `index.html` file doesn't need the script tags:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I just include the packages in my JavaScript file:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'fullcalendar'
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css'

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar()
})
```

I'm still looking for a way to clean up the way I import the CSS file, but at least I don't have an HTML file that looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css' />
    <script src='node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='entry.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how to include the CSS file more cleanly.

Comment: Did you ever figure out to add css cleanly?

Comment: This was the best I got.