# Display Chart.js chart in Node.js

Tags: node.js, chart.js

I am working on a software project with a team, and I would like to add a page that displays a bar chart using Chart.js. The project is using Node.js, and we are using Express.js to render the views on our server.

The issue is that when I displayed the page with the bar chart on its own, it worked just fine. When I tried to run the server (i.e. node app.js), however, the page wouldn't display the chart, no matter where I placed my JavaScript code for drawing the chart.

Here is my EJS file with the chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title>Connect Concordia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
      <!-- load bootsrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400">Your browser does not support the canvas feature.</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Strongly Agree', 'Agree', 'Neither Agree nor Disagree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly Disagree'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Number of Responses',
                data: [5, 10, 6, 3, 2],
                backgroundColor: "rgb(100, 100, 100)"
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 50,
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code to render the page on the app, found in a larger file called routes.js:

```
res.render('sp-results.ejs')
```

Note: I myself am new to Node.js, so if there is anything else I need to know please inform me. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Upon inspecting the page using Chrome, I found this error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

From that, I found out that the reason why the chart isn't displaying is because the server can't reference the library. Since Chart.js isn't a Node.js library, how can I 'require' the Chart.js library?

Comment: Are there any errors shown on the console when you go to that page?

Comment: No, it just displays a blank canvas. The HTML works for sure as I got it to display a <p> tagged line as a test.

Comment: Did you try putting your chart.js code inside a `window.onload` to see if its an issue where the code is running before the DOM is ready?

Comment: Just tried it right now, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Is it like this?
<script>
window.onload = function(){
<chart.js code here>
};
</script>

Comment: Yup, that's right.  Here is an [example](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/bar/bar.html#L63)

Comment: I just found the error actually: 

upon inspecting the page using Chrome, I found this error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I'm guessing that my server has to know where to find Chart.js. How can I do that?

Comment: Let me submit an answer to show you

Comment: Thanks! Just updated the question so it makes more sense.

Comment: I just added the answer...and shortly updated it right after.  Hopefully this will solve it!

Comment: Hello, I hope it's not too late, how did you solve your problem? I am trying to implement a chart in hbs but I don't know how to pass the chart configuration to the template from the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could try is not initializing your chart until the document is for sure ready.  You can do this using `window.onload`.

```
window.onload = function() {
  // put chart.js code here
}
```

Also, I notice that you are trying to link to a chart.js build located in your `node_modules` folder.  I'm not exactly sure how to do this in express in an ejs file, but take a look at this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder) for an example on how to handle this.

You can always use the script hosted on a [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js) to quickly validate your page is working.  Here is an example.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js">
```

Comment: Dude, you're actually a life saver! Thank you so much! :)

Now I may begin to _start_ working on my actual code XD. Such is the life of a programmer :P

Comment: No problem!  I know how it goes ;)