# How to include header file for Chart.js after downloading it?

Tags: chart.js

I've recently downloaded Chart.js by first installing node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/
and then ran

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

on my command prompt from https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html.
I am ready to do some web development and have no clue how to include the Chart.js header file for an HTML program I plan to write. I am using a Windows 10 OS. How would I go about adding the header file (going to use atom for the text editor)? I don't see chart.js after doing "dir", only saw package-lock.json and package.json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914504/2358409