# ChartJS on NodeJS: error Chart is not defined

Tags: node.js, chart.js

I'm trying to use ChartJS on NodeJS, but it doesn't work. I installed with `npm install chart.js --save` and I created the simplest possible test as indicated below, but error `Chart is not defined` displayed. I've already tried to copy the file "chart.js" to the same directory, I've already tried to point to the `node_modules/chart.js/....` directory, but I can't make it work. Also I can't point the file `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js`, because system should work" stand alone "

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script>
        var chrt = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
        var data = {
            labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            }]
        };
        var myFirstChart = new Chart(chrt).Bar(data);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle link for us?

Comment: I've seen some examples in fiddle and there everything works fine. On my system no ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are importing the chart library. It should work this way *(as long as everything is set correctly)* :

```
...
<script src="chart.js"></script>
...
```

However, the actual issue might occur, because of the syntax you are using to construct the chart.

When you install Chart.js module using **`npm install chart.js --save`**, it installs the latest version of Chart.js *(which is at the moment 2.6)*, but you are using old syntax *(which is for v1.x)* while creating the chart.

Here is the correct syntax for creating a chart in Chart.js version 2.6 :

```
...
var chrt = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
var data = {
   labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul"],
   datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
      borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
   }]
};
var myFirstChart = new Chart(chrt, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: data
});
...
```

Comment: Cool!! Now is working!!!! As you said @ℊααnd, it was only incorrect syntax. There's one thing I've not yet figured out: Why system can't find the file `./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js`? To make it work it was necessary to copy this file to my `/javascripts` directory. If there is another way better than that, I would like to know how to do. Thank you!

Comment: A tip about this new version, which is in "chartjs.org": By default the chart is self-adjusting to the window, so to prevent this, just put the "canvas object" in a `div` tag, as shown here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Comment: TRY - `../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js`

Comment: I've already tried using the real path, but nothing works. The only way it works is by copying the file to a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that you are using framework or not but I try `npm install chart.js` then create `index.html` in the same level with `node_modules`. Then I import it like this.

`<script src="./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>`

Work fine ,please try and if it not work please provide some more details.

Comment: I've tried this but it also didn't work. I've already copied the `/dist/Chart.js` file to a separate directory and then it gives another error: `(intermediate value).Bar is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to avoid referencing your modules in your front-end files. Instead consider creating a route for your module files and then reference the route in your front-end files.

Example:

index.html

```
<script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
app.get('/bootstrap.min.js', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js');
});
```

For more specifics please see this great answer courtesy of @jfriend00 [How to include scripts located inside the node_modules folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder)