# how to run bootstrap and jquery in nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm-install

In the following picture you can see the structure of my project on the left and on the right side is the list of all dependencies.

[image]

I typed the command "npm install" via gitbash, but when I view the page source, neither jquery nor bootstrap show.

How can I load jquery and bootstrap via npm?
Hope you can help.

Comment: You should type `npm install` in your `terminal` and not in your `gitbash` and also you should be in the same directory as your `package.json`

Comment: I don't think that this is an issue cause all other dependencies were successfully installed via gitbash. Well regardless I just tried quickly but still when I view the site I see nothing of bootstrap and jquery

Comment: Are you checking inside your `node_modules` folder ?

Comment: Open `node_modules` folder, jquery and bootstrap must be there.

Comment: And you can't see them in your `site`, without some additional work: build tool, etc

Comment: @alexmac. Yes I see them in the nodules folder. How exactly can I make my header.html read them?

Comment: Hope you can help me get away through this cause its my first time trying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include scripts located inside the node\_modules folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder)

Comment: Why not just use the CDN version on your index.html or download the min version and save it to your static directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load front end components you can

1. Use Bower, Grunt or Gulp or
2. Use Webpack, with help of Webpack you can do everything directly in NPM

References:

https://webpack.js.org/

https://medium.com/javascript-training/introduction-to-using-npm-as-a-build-tool-b41076f488b0