# How to include a script for use in the html

Tags: javascript, npm, tinymce

I am trying to experiment with [tinymce npm](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/#packagemanagerinstalloptions). I am following their guide and I am stuck here

`Include this line of code in the <head> of your HTML page:
<script src="/path/to/tinymce.min.js"></script>`.

Now inside my head in html, I put this code

`<script src="node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>`.

however in the console, there is an error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I also find another stack overflow question related to my problem and came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder)

I also tried using the solution here and this is what I did but still the same error.

`<script src="scripts/tinymce.min.js"></script>`

here is a screenshot of my sample project.

[image: tinymce]

I am trying to get `tinymce.min.js` to `index.html` which is inside `views/blog folder`

My question is, how can I make this work?

Comment: The relative path from the index.html file would be `"../../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix for you would be to use a CDN instead of NPM.

Replace this: `<script src="node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>`

With this: `<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tinymce"></script>`

Below I give my guess at the issue, but I can't be sure without inspecting your whole project:

I think you are neither building nor serving your project. In your sample project I don't see any webpack, gulp, grunt, or other build tool config file. I also don't see anything like Browserify or similar. Those tools would be able to read your script pointing to a local npm folder and replace it with the script from the npm folder. Without those tools, your browser will think the `src=` string is a web url and the resource will not be found.

As I mentioned, a CDN is a simple fix because that is a real website hosting the script you are asking for. A more complicated approach which is used in commercial development is to have a complete build process and then a server.

Comment: Sorry for not including build tools of sorts. I plan to make this project as quick as possible because it is only a sample file to test tinymce. Thank you for your answer. It works now.