# Trouble with using an npm package (leaflet addon) in html <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, leaflet

I am trying to include a leaflet package in my locally hosted website. The idea of the website is to allow the user to query for tweets from the Twitter API (the request is sent fro the HTML page to a NodeJs server running on express) and have these sent back and loaded in the leaflet map using a bounding box to place the marker. Since most tweets don't come with a geotag or bounding box information, I thought the next best thing would be to take the name of the location (e.g. London) stored in the tweet metadata and do a reverse geocoding to get the bounding box from the city/location name. To do this reverse geocoding I thought I would use a leaflet add-on called [leaflet-geosearch](https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch), since the other common option of using the Google Maps API seem not to be free. I have tried now many ways of importing this package into my project, but all with no luck. The documentation shows that it can be loaded using

```
// import
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';

// setup
const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

// search
const results = await provider.search({ query: input.value });
```

So I tried to load it in this fashion in my HTML code inside of a  tag as such:

```js
<script type="module">
    import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';

    // setup
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

</script>
```

But it tells me that I need to add a '/' for a relative pathway. So I tried to load it using a relative path to numerous different scripts in the node_modules/leaflet-geosearch folder:

```js
<script type="module">
    import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from './node_modules/leaflet-geosearch/dist/geosearch.js';

    // setup
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

</script>
```

The above method told me that "'geosearch.js' does not provide an export named 'OpenStreetMapProvider'", so I went back and looked through the files some more and found a file named 'openStreetMapProvider.js' and so tried to load this:

```js
<script type="module">
    import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from './node_modules/leaflet-geosearch/lib/providers/openStreetMapProvider.js';

    // setup
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

</script>
```

But it gave me the same error "... does not provide an export named 'OpenStreetMapProvider'".

I have tried to load it directly into my nodeJS server script,

```js
// import
const OpenStreetMapProvider = require('leaflet-geosearch');

// setup
const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
```

But when I then try to run the server on a local port it throws the Reference error below.

[image]

Does anyone know how I could properly load and use this module in my HTML page? I have seen some answers that say browserify can help in such cases, but if that was really necessary then the ReadME on the package's github page should have mentioned this, so I feel like there must be a more straightforward solution to this.

Comment: if you want to use it in the index.html page then use [cdns](https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch/#using-a-cdn) to import the library directly. It is painful to import `node_modules` into html, it is not a common practise plus it is [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder) as you expose how your server is structured

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that I had also tried going down the CDN route, but when I try to import as such: ```<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>``` I get the following error ```Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.```. I tried doing the thing where you add 'types': 'module' to the packahe.json but this didn't do anything to help

Comment: Actually, nevermind that error was from a different import attempt I forgot to remove. It looks like it is working now. Not sure why it didn't work the last time I tried it, but thanks anyways :)