# How do I access node modules client-side when building an Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs, intl-tel-input

I'm trying to use [intl-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-tel-input) in a project I'm building using [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs).

I have `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in my **app.js** which means Express serves all static files from the public directory in my project.

I am unable to integrate [intl-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-tel-input) as it's a node module and the relevant css and js files are located in `/node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/...` and they are not served by Express at all. Thus, when I try to link to them in my Ejs template, I get a 404 error.

How do I solve this? All the ideas I have seem like the wrong approach.

Comment: have you examine the 'examples'  : https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/examples/template.html.ejs  and using them as skeleton for what you need in your work

Comment: @RobertRowntree yes I had a look. It doesn't solve my problem as those examples don't show how to link to the source css/js files when using Express.

Comment: that sounds like a problem that a bundler like webpack will solve .  the path locations and disparate needs of client side vs server are resolved by the bundler ( repackaging ) in a separate build step before u start the app

Comment: @RobertRowntree I did look into Webpack as a possible solution but decided against it for the extra complexity it would add. I've never used it before so would've had to put in some extra work. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder) to be an extremely quick, effective and simple solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a while and exploring solutions like Webpack, RequireJS and other not so elegant ones, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder) to be the most relevant, easy and effective solution for this particular problem.