# How do I set <script src> to include a javascript file outside the root folder set in express.static()?

Tags: html, node.js, express, path

I set `app.use(express.static('public'))`, following is my folder structure (just the usual stuff) and I start my express from `package.json` 's parent folder.

```
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
├── readme.md
├── src
│   ├── database/
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── routes/
│   └── testdrive/
├── tsconfig.json
```

Sometime I want to quick test if a javascript file in `testdrive` folder works in the browser, I tried to edit my `index.html` (inside the `public` folder) like the following but it does not work.

```
<script src="../src/testdrive/foo.js"></script>
or 
<script src="src/testdrive/foo.js"></script>
```

Browsers both resolve to `http://localhost:3000/src/testdrive/foo.js` and complain 404

I have to  add `app.use('/scripts', express.static('src'))` and edit script tag as `<script src="/scripts/testdrive/foo.js"></script>` to make it work.

So why doesn't the relative path work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I set  to include a javascript file outside the root folder set in express.static()?

The default value of the `dotfiles` config option for `express.static()` prevents it from accessing files outside the directory you tell it to look in for security reasons.  You can turn that config option off to allow `..` and `.` in the URL with `express.static()`, but doing so is a potentially bad security risk (allowing an attacker to access lots of other files on your server) unless you have other code that ensures the URL is safe.  This problem can always be solved safely by just either using multiple `express.static()` statements to each point to their own public root or by reorganizing all the public files to have a common root that doesn't contain any non-public files.

First off, you almost never want to use relative paths for resources in your HTML page.  The browser will always send an absolute URL to the server so if you use a relative path in the HTML page, then it will combine the path from the page's URL to create an absolute path before sending the request to the server.  Keep in mind that an http server is mostly stateless so each incoming http request arrives separately and is not "from" a particular web page.  Thus, they each must stand on their own and that's why the server doesn't have relative path requests.

So, if you use relative paths in your resource URLs, then what gets sent to the server will end up depending upon the path of the containing page as the browser will make it into an absolute path.  That is almost never what you want.  Things are just simpler if you use absolute paths in your resource URLs.

Second, the `src` directory you show is not below `public` so that's why no URL can ever match something in the `src` directory when using only `app.use(express.static('public'))`.  That can ONLY access resources inside the `public` directory tree.  You show `src` at the same level as `public`.

As for your combination that does work of:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static('src'))

<script src="/scripts/testdrive/foo.js"></script>
```

This is because you're now properly pointing `express.static()` at the `src`.
directory.  Note that the `/scripts` part of what you have there could be anything.  It could be:

```
app.use('/whatever', express.static('src'))

<script src="/whatever/testdrive/foo.js"></script>
```

All, they have to do is match each other.  You could also have left out the `/scripts` part entirely:

```
app.use(express.static('src'))

<script src="/testdrive/foo.js"></script>
```

But, this leads to some potential confusion if you are also using:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

because Express will look in both places for a matching path and if you have any common paths between `public` and `src`, then whichever `app.use()` is declared first will always be the one that matches the common names.

---

Also, note that `<script src="../src/testdrive/foo.js"></script>` did not work because by default `express.static()` will ignore either `./` or `../` because it can be an attack vector allowing an attacker to explore your server's file system by fetch files outside of your `public` folder.  See the `dotfiles` [option](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) for `express.static()`.

Comment: So the answer to my question "How do I set `<script src>` to include a javascript file outside `express.static()` setting?" is NO you can't because expressjs will prevent you from accessing files outside what you set in `express.static()`. Right ?

Comment: @Qiulang - `express.static()` will (by default) prevent the use of `.` and `..` in URLs.  That is configurable by you (it's a config option for `express.static()`), but allowing the dots is a security risk so you shouldn't be allowing the dots unless you were otherwise making sure the URL was safe.  I've added this summary to the start of my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I know it is bad and as I said in my question I only need that when I debug my code as a **quick and dirty** solution (so I don't need to edit my `index.ts`) but as you point out if I need to edit `dotfiles` then it is really bad, I better just edit my `index.ts`.