# in node.js how do you pass a "require" object to jade?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I created a node module which contains one simple js file. I want to use this js function inside my jade file. In music.js I require the module "myplayer":

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
   var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
var locals = res.locals;
    locals.myplayer = require('myplayer');
    // locals.section is used to set the currently selected
// item in the header navigation.
    locals.section = 'music';
// Render the view
view.render('music');
};
```

I know that it is accessing this file because I have a console print statement contained inside the myplayer js file that appears in my terminal when I go to music.jade in my browser.
Then in my music.jade file I try to use the myplayer function, myplayer().tryplay.

```
extends ../layouts/default
block content
.container: .jumbotron
    img(src='/images/logo.svg', width='160')
    h1 Welcome
    audio#test(controls='')
        source(src='/mymusic/cold.mp3')
        | Your browser does not support the audio element.
    button Click me
        if (section == 'music')
            li sees variable
    p The Music page is currently under construction
    hr
block js        
script.
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(myplayer().tryplay)   
    });
```

It seems like I'm passing the variable correctly since I'm doing exactly the same as locals.section, which effects whether "sees variable" gets printed.

The error I get is "Reference Error: myplayer is not defined"

So I have a number of questions. Is the "if (section == 'music')" statement actually a jquery command, not css? But I don't see a "$" or anything to signify that.

"Section" clearly is a variable of value "music", but I can't figure out how to print it out either inside the music.jade css script or in the internal javascript.

And last, of course is, why can't "$("button").click(myplayer().tryplay)" find the object myplayer?

It seems like I'm just making simple syntax errors, but I'm afraid I'm really lost.

Thanks for any help.

---

This is what I'm trying to reproduce, but with node_modules:

```
extends ../layouts/default
block content
.container: .jumbotron
img(src='/images/logo.svg', width='160')
h1 Welcome
audio#test(controls='')
    source(src='/mymusic/cold.mp3')
    | Your browser does not support the audio element.
    button Click me
    p The Music page is currently under construction
    hr
block js        
script(src='/jplay/my_jquery.js')
script.
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(tryplay)
    });
```

Here's the my_jquery.js file:

```
var tryplay = function(){
    $("#test")[0].play();}
```

The above 2 files work fine.
The myplayer node_modules main file I created is:

```
var exports = module.exports = {} ; 
function startup () {
var tryplay = function(){
    $("#test")[0].play();}
console.log ("runUserScript");
}
startup ();
```

I wasn't intending to create a string, I wanted to pass the function on to music.jade. Clearly, using locals.myplayer is not correct?

---

So I changed music.js to:

```
    var keystone = require('keystone');
    exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
    var myplayer = require('myplayer');
    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;
   //  locals.myplayer = require('myplayer');
    // locals.section is used to set the currently selected
    // item in the header navigation.
    locals.section = 'music';

    // Render the view
    view.render('music');
    };
```

And I changed music.jade to:

```
extends ../layouts/default
block content
.container: .jumbotron
    img(src='/images/logo.svg', width='160')
    h1 !{section}
    audio#test(controls='')
        source(src='/mymusic/cold.mp3')
        | Your browser does not support the audio element.
    button Click me
    p The Music page is currently under construction
    hr
block js        
script.
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){myplayer().tryplay})   
    });
```

But now I get "ReferenceError: myplayer is not defined", so I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: I'm confused, you're importing code with `require`, and then trying to use it as a string for your locals variable? What does the `myplayer` module export ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading this post:
[Script path for ExpressJS in node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397379/script-path-for-expressjs-in-node-modules)
I realized I was doing things correctly to begin with. Your client side javascript files are supposed to be in the public folder, not the node_modules folder. The above link describes how to access the files in the node_modules if you wanted to. 
The reason I was trying to do this was because I downloaded the jplayer with "npm install" and in order to get it running I had to copy the jquery.jplayer.js file to the public directory and that didn't seem correct.
What I should have done is use "bower" as these 2 sites suggest?
https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer and
[How to include scripts located inside the node_modules folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464168/how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder)